# How do I make an amd64 version of my application?

Tags: application-development, quickly, launchpad, pygtk

I am here because I am able to successfully upload the i386 build of my program to launchpad, but I have no idea how to create a native 64-bit application. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What architectures your application is built for depends on the `Architecture` field in your debian/control file.

- *all* will build architecture-independent packages.
- *any* will build architecture-depend packages, once for each of the supported architectures.

You can also explicitly specify the architectures that should be build (e.g. `Architecture: amd64 armel`).